What does the error message ""No internal type for both IPv4 and IPv6 Addresses" (A+AAAA) records available for <address.domain>" mean?
What does this error message from nslookup on Windows (10) mean?
"No internal type for both IPv4 and IPv6 Addresses (A+AAAA) records available for internalname.internaldomain.tld"

Googling I see some people have had this problem with funky DNS setups, possibly intersecting with bad IPv6 setups, but no-one has suggested what the error message itself might mean.  If I understand it its possible I can work out a root cause.
Background
I am trying to diagnose a DNS issue for someone on our VPN from their home.  I think I've narrowed the difference down to their home router's behaviour when responding to VPN DNS requests (that should be going down the VPN due to "Connection-specific DNS Suffix", but are not).
When I look up that internal address my router correctly says:
Server:  gateway.my.place
Address:  192.168.1.1

*** gateway.my.place can't find internalname.internaldomain.tld: Non-existent domain

But my colleague gets:
Server:  router.his.place
Address:  192.168.0.1
 
*** No internal type for both IPv4 and IPv6 Addresses (A+AAAA) records available for internalname.internaldomain.tld

I suspect this "non-failure" is preventing windows from going over to the connection-specific DNS.
Regarding the IPv6 aspect in the error and other posts - here I (working) have (working) IPv6, but my colleague doesn't seem to have IPv6 enabled at all.

I've just encountered the same error for a remote user. We use TailScale for VPN and this ONE new user out of about 20 cannot find our server with a 192.168.xxx.yyy address, as delivered by our public DNS entry for server.domain.tld Changing their DNS from their ISP to 1.1.1.1 (cloudfire) or 2.2.2.2 (google) does not help. Maybe it has something to do with iPv6?

I don't know what error message means exactly.
But by the sound of situation you describe, I'd say I had quite similar problem recently. In my case I had two routers in the same network, one was running DHCP, and the other DNS.
And when I tried to forward dns requests from second to first one for local names I got this error.
Cause for the error was a "Rebind protection" of OpenWrt, which prevents upstream DNS servers resolving into RFC1918 addresses (your 192.168s, 172.16s, etc). Since in my case it was exactly what was needed I simply disabled this option at Network > DHCP and DNS > Filter > Rebind protection.

Thanks, that's really helpful - in this case it could be plausibly involved as it is resolving addresses in the RFC1918 address space.
I suspect there's a root-cause still missing here - I have to assume that this means the resolution DNS on our VPN is being handled by their OpenWRT router - that suggests there's a fault in the "Connection-specific DNS Suffix" configuration that should be sending those requests down the VPN only.
As to the error message - I'd need to see the returned DNS responses but it could be that OpenWRT is returning a black-ball IPv6 address that is not ULA block.
